# ¿Cómo añadir una categoría de otra tabla al producto que este relacionado?

Tags: php

Tengo la idea de mostrar en los resultados de la consulta el nombre de la categoría que está relacionado el producto.

Este diseño me sugiere @Lixus en su [comentario...](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90228/c%C3%B3mo-a%C3%B1adir-una-categor%C3%ADa-de-otra-base-de-datos?noredirect=1#comment165990_90228)

> Este diseño de la tabla seria ideal solo para una categoría del producto relacionado.

Tabla de **categorias**

```
id_cat       title     
  1           PHP
  2         MYSQLI
  3         JQUERY
```

> Pero si en el producto estuviera relacionado con más de una categoría lo ideal seria añadir el `id_pro` del producto a la tabla de **categorias**

```
id_cat       title    id_pro   
  1           PHP       1
  2         MYSQLI     NULL
  3         JQUERY     NULL
  4          HTML       1
```

> Y así poder mostrar un resultado de está manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla de **products**

```
  id_pro          title          categoria
    1           live glypicon        1
```

Cómo se puede observar en la tabla de  **categorias** en la columna `id_pro` se encuentra el número `1` que se basa al número `1` del `id_pro` de la tabla de **products**.

Y en la tabla **products** se encuentra el número `1` en la columna `categoria` que es referente al nombre de la categoría que pertenece.

> **NOTA:** No se si el diseño de la base de datos y las tablas sean las correctas pero mi idea es poder mostrar el siguiente resultado de la imagen. ***Teniendo muy en cuenta que el producto puede estar relacionado a más de una categoría tal como mostraba en la primera imagen donde existía dos categorías para el mismo producto `PHP`&`HTML`***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi consulta:**

```
function newpro(){
    global $con;
    $sql = "Select * from products where id_product and active='1' order by id_product ASC limit 1";
    $rows = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $new_products = mysqli_num_rows($rows);

    if($new_products==0){
        echo"No hay cursos nuevos para mostrar";
    }else{
        while ($pro = mysqli_fetch_array($rows)) {

            for ($i=0; $i<8; $i++) {

            echo '<div class="four-column middle-pro">
        <div class="frame-item">
          <a href="'.$pro['url'].'">
            <img src="assets/img/upload/image/'.$pro['image'].'" alt="'.$pro['title'].'" />
          </a>
          <div class="all-description">
            <div class="women">
              <h2><a href="#">'.$pro['title'].'</a></h2>
              <h3><a href="">'.$pro['subtitle'].'</a></h3>
              <h6><a href="">AQUI QUIERO MOSTRAR LA CATEGORIA</a></h6>
            </div>
            <div class="price align-right">
              <p><label>$'.$pro['price_old'].'</label><em class="item_price">$'.$pro['price'].'</em></p>
                          <!--<div class="clearfix"></div>-->
            </div>
            <!--<div class="center add">
              <a href="#">más información...</a>
            </div>-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>';
        }}
    }
}
```

Comment: Relacionado con el código pero no con la pregunta en sí: ¿En la tabla de productos tienes una clave foránea a categorías y en la tabla de categorías tienes una clave foránea a productos? Parece un diseño bastante raro.

Comment: ¿Son dos bases de datos o dos tablas?

Comment: @J.Mick Es raro que la tabla A tenga una clave foránea para la tabla B, y la tabla B tenga una clave foránea para la tabla A. Es la primera vez que veo algo así. Puede que con una doble relación 1:1/1:n, pero no sé cuál es el caso en particular de tu base de datos. ¿Qué simboliza cada clave foránea en esas tablas? (sólo por curiosidad)

Comment: Normalmente eso se resuelve haciendo `LEFT JOIN` uniendo con `p.categoria` y `c.id_categoria`, el problema es que tu diseño  rompe con un punto importante en la normalización de datos, si la relación de ambas tablas es `n:n` te recomiendo hagas otra tabla producto_categoria donde solo tengas id_producto / id_categoria donde hagas las relaciones necesarias para poder encontrar correctamente tu información

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro realmente las tablas ni la base de datos tiene una clave foránea... Realmente los datos se muestra nativamente con **php** algo similar a esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670811/display-categories-and-subcategories-in-php-mysql)

Comment: No recuerdo muy bien el ejemplo, no se sí estoy mal pero todo se realiza nativamente con **php** en su consulta:
`$query = "select * from categories where id_categoria = '".$id_product."'";` El problema es como se puede realizar dentro del `while` otra consulta para mostrar el nombre de la categoría o algo así @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro He editado nuevamente mi pregunta espero este más claro con la nueva edición dilculpa si estoy mal con el diseño de las tablas.

Comment: @Lixus He editado nuevamente mi pregunta espero este más claro con la nueva edición dilculpa si estoy mal con el diseño de las tablas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que decís, sin centrarme en el código, tu diseño de base de datos está mal.

Cada categoría puede tener varios productos, y cada producto puede tener varias categorías. Por lo tanto, deberías tener 3 tablas.

Una de categorías:

```
id_cat title
```

Otra de productos:

```
id_prod title
```

Y otra que una las dos (produ-cat):

```
id_cat id_prod
```

Y tu query pasaría a ser:

```
    select * from productos left join produ-cat on id_prod = id_prod left join
 categorias on id_cat = id_cat where title = 'producto'
```

(El query es solo la idea del que deberías tener)

Con un query así, obtendrías el resultado deseado de las categorías para un determinado producto. Y así puedes recorrerlas tranquilamente.

Comment: No entendí, Sólo una duda en el query del ejemplo dado si existe más de una categoría se mostrara o no... Realmente es necesario otra tabla no puede ser solo las dos... No existe alguna forma de evitar una tercera taba...

Comment: No. Debe existir otra tabla.. que pasa si un producto esta en mas de una categoria? Y si una categoria tiene mas de un producto?